# How to allow to reconnect to internet connection in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am showing online and offline status in my application by using snackbar as follow:

```js
fromEvent(window, 'offline').subscribe(event => {
  this.showSnackbar('No Internet', null, 'Dismiss');
});

fromEvent(window, 'online').subscribe(event => {
  this.showSnackbar('Internet Connected', 2000);
});
```

Now, the objective is to allow the user to **try to reconnect to internet connection after the status becomes offline** for example like in **slack app**. I try and search a lot but I did not find any solution. Is there any way to do this? If someone knows then please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "try to reconnect to internet" by that do you mean to retry requests that failed because of the offline state ?

Comment: @serrulien No, try to reconnect to internet connection for example wifi

Comment: A web application cannot access directly the internet interface, the browser handles it for us. We cannot switch the wifi hotspot from a javascript application however we can know when internet connection is on or off (and that's what you did).